# Nginx subdomain configuration is wrong

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to configure my Nginx version 1.10.2 as a reverse proxy hosted in a CentOS 7 OS. I have several applications running on the same WildFly 10 server. Those applications are available at `http://213.xxx.xxx.xxx/app1` and `http://213.xxx.xxx.xxx/app2`. I created a subdomain for app2 `http://app2.example.com`. My `nginx.conf` file contains those servers:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://213.xxx.xxx.xxx/app1;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app2.example.com www.app2.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://213.xxx.xxx.xxx/app2;
    }
}
```

From my web browser I can reach app1 at URL `example.com`. But I can't reach app2. When I send a request to `app2.example.com`, it redirects me to `app2.example.com/app2`. Can someone tells me what is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use `app1.example.com`?

Comment: I don't have sub domain for app1 but it's the same with app3.

Comment: I meant can you change `proxy_pass http://213.xxx.xxx.xxx/app1;`; and see if `app2.example.com` loads `app1` fine

Comment: In my second server configuration, if I change `proxy_pass http://213.xxx.xxx.xxx/app2` to `proxy_pass http://213.xxx.xxx.xxx/app1`, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are app does the redirects and that is why app1 works and app2 doesn't work. Now there are few things you can try

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app2.example.com www.app2.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://213.xxx.xxx.xxx/app2;
        proxy_redirect http://213.xxx.xxx.xxx/app2/ http://$host/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Can you debug using methods i listed in this article? http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/. Post more details in the question with the details